# Read-write file locking in Obj-C (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, filesystems

I'm finding the way to read/write file with locking. Does iOS sdk support this feature?

I see there are 2 ways to read-write file.

First with `NSFileManager` and another is `NSInputStream`/`NSOutputStream`, but I haven't seen the way to handle file concurrency, for example, open file with write lock.

Or I have to implement those locking by myself?

Answer (score 3):

In general, iOS apps don't bother locking files because the documents are sandboxed away from other applications. flock() is implemented in iOS, but I haven't personally used it. It might be useful if you have multiple threads or classes sharing the same files.

Comment: I would try either flock() or even just an internal thread-safe data structure containing a list of your locked files. You could use an NSMutableSet, for example, to contain a list of full pathnames for all files that are locked. You'll have to make sure to use @synchronized whenever accessing the set, but that shouldn't be too hard. Fair access would be a little bit harder to implement -- where the thread waiting the longest gets to access the file.

Answer (score 1):

`NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:append:` keeps a write lock to the file.
You can still use `fopen` and `fstream` (in objc++) and they will work just like in a regular linux.